# Textarea for Drupal 8 text fields content types

Tags: 8, entities

Currently there is no option to select textarea as a widget for a *long* text field in a content type. What solutions are there? And why was this removed as this was in core Drupal 7.

Answer (score 5):

A long textfield is a textarea by default, there's no need to explicity configure it as such. For example here I created a textfield with label "Text" as `plain, long`:

[image]

And this is how it looks in the `node/add` page:

[image]